# Best approach to handle API versioning in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

We have a big project with many models. We have a web app as well as mobile apps we have to change our mobile apps versions. There are a lot of business logic changes but we do not want to effect our previous version and as well as add new business logic what is best approach so that our web and mobile apps with all version work smoothly the challenge we are facing is to handle business logic written in models.

Answer (score 1):

You can use versionist it is pretty helpful

You can refer these links

1) https://github.com/bploetz/versionist

2) http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

3) https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/adding-versions-rails-api/